# Django - How to find which field(s) a queryset is being ordered by?

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have a queryset that may be ordered or not.
When it's orderded, I'd like to find the fields used in such ordering.

Let's say that my queryset is:

```
Store.objects.order_by('name', '-id')
```

Is it possible, given such queryset, to get the tuple `('name', '-id')`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the list of ordering criteria, accessing the `query` object:

```
>>> qs = Store.objects.order_by('name', '-id')
>>> print qs.query.order_by
['name', '-id']
```

Comment: This does not work for default ordering (ie specified in `Meta` with `ordering=`).

Comment: If thats the case i think you can just get it from the instance: `instance._meta.ordering`